# How to get the data using parent id in hibernate inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate

I m using hiberntate table per subclass inheritance concept. Here is my sample code

```
@Entity
@Table
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Payment{
   @Id
   @Column
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private int id;

   @Column
   private double amount; 
}

@Entity
@Table
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "payment_id")
public class CreditCard extends Payment{
  @Column
  private String CreditCardType;
}
```

Here while getting the Child class by it's parent id,  i am getting the exception like Unknown column 'this_.id' in 'where clause'. My query is

```
List<CreditCard> creditCardList =
    getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(CreditCard.class,   
   "card").add(Restrictions.eq("card.id", id)).list();
```

Comment: You have not explicitly mentioned  column names in the mapping. This is necessary if the column names in the DB are not same as properties in respective classes.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But the column names are same as the property names

Answer (score 1):

In your parent class the Identifier property is named as `id` but in child class you are mapping the `PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` with `payment_id`. As per your comment I believe you have same names for properties and columns.

Change the column name to `id` instead of `payment_id` as below and it should work.

```
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")
```

Comment: Is your problem rectified?

Answer (score 0):

Change your child entity class as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")
public class CreditCard extends Payment{
  @Column
  private String CreditCardType;
}
```

Refer to following link for the same also:
http://www.javatpoint.com/hibernate-table-per-subclass-using-annotation-tutorial-example